# Determine the probability that at least one of them will be in class on a given day.

Tags: probability

Question: John and James both registered for a certain course in a university but did not attend all the lessons as both of them are working part-time. John is absent for $20\%$ of the time and James is absent for $40\%$ of the time. The absences of the two students are independent. Determine the probability that at least one of them will be in class on a given day. If at least one of them is in class on a given day, determine the probability that John is in class that day.

Are my answers correct?

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like another user pointed out, your answer to the second question is not correct. You set it up correctly but $P($John is in class, at least one of them is in class$)$ is not $0.8 * 0.92$. It is equivalent to $P($John is in class). If this is not intuitive you can see this by writing $P($John is in class, at least one of them is in class$)$ as $P($John is in class and James is in class$) + P($John is in class and James is not in class$) = 0.8*0.6 + 0.8*0.4 = 0.8,$ so the answer to the second question is $0.8/0.92$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use complementary probability. There is an 8% chance that neither of them are there, so there is a 92% chance that at least one of them is there. In 80 out of those 92 cases, John is there. Therefore, the probability that John is in class given that at least one of them is is $\frac{80}{92} = \frac{20}{23}.$ In particular, the given answer to the second question is wrong.

Comment: thank you so much!